# glOrtho is not working?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

```
 /* OpenGL animation code goes here */
        glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0f,512.0f,0.0f,512.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
        glPushMatrix ();
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(x,y,0.0f);
        //glRotatef (theta, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f (0.0f, 1.0f);
        glColor3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f (0.8f, -0.5f);
        glColor3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f (-0.8f, -0.5f);
        glEnd ();
        glPopMatrix ();

        SwapBuffers (hDC);
        //theta += 0.1f;
        Sleep(1);
        }
```

This is the main simple opengl loop.

Recently, I come back to study Opengl (after leaving it for like 2 yrs). The problem is, I tried to use glOrtho to create 2D environment, but It is not working. I mean, the program seems to ignore glOrtho call (no errors, no warnings, no projection, nothing). This causes the vertex (0,1) of GL_TRIANGLE to hit the top of windows, and anything more than 1.0f will fly off the viewport (it is still an identity matrix I think?). I tried changing the parameters but no changes occur in the vieewport. I don't know if I am missing something (maybe missing some initialization step or some deprecation that I am not aware of).

Comment: By the way, it should rather be `GL_MODELVIEW` (without the `_MATRIX` suffix).

Comment: Yeah, and ironically that was my problem! I don't know why dev-c++ won't promp error on GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX (is it some kind of constant?)

Comment: This constant also exists, but it is used for something completely different (for retrieving the current modelview matrix with `glGetFloatv` or `glGetDoublev`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glOrtho(0.0f,512.0f,0.0f,512.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
```

This projection effectively selects the box of width 512, height 512 and depth 1 units to be the visible world space. However the vertices you specify will all be within a very small subset of the box, i.e. within one unit.

```
glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f (0.0f, 1.0f);
glColor3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f (0.8f, -0.5f);
glColor3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f (-0.8f, -0.5f);
glEnd();
```

I think you just confused the use of glOrtho with glViewport.

Comment: Can you help me clarify my understanding? I thought glViewport specify how the final result of render scene is mapped onto windows' coordinate, and glOrtho simply take like a snapshot inside the world coordinate. I just expected the triangle to plot on the graph with domain 0 - 512 and range 0 - 512 with vertices (0,1) (0.8,-0.5) (-0.8,-0.5). I don't really understand what you means by "small subset of the box"?

Comment: 1.0f is much smaller than 512.0f. Both numbers are in the same coordinate space, so you are rendering in a 1/512 = 0.001953125 of the frustum, that is quite a "small subset of the box".

Comment: I tried increasing the size, but it seem the triangle just expand out of screen when I do so (I increase them by around 10x, which should be significantly smaller than 512x512)

Comment: @user385261: Say your window is of size 512×512

Comment: @user385261: Then with the choosen projection, all geometry will be rendered in the one lower leftmost pixel.